# Update the count using row number()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I want to update the count in TABLE1 every time when transaction processed on T1.VALUE. The problem TABLE2 CONTAINS T1.VALUE more than one time i want to set that count in T1.COUNT_VAL

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1
    SET
        T1.COUNT_VAL = nvl(T1.COUNT_VAL,0) + 1
WHERE
    T1.VALUE IN (
        SELECT 
            T2.VALUE,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T2.ID  ORDER BY T2.VALUE)
        FROM
            TABLE2 T2
        WHERE
          T2.VALUE_REF = 'HGV00005x'
    ORDER BY T2.ID,
        T2.VALUE
    );
```

I tried this but error like below

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `ORDER BY` clause from the subquery, this:

```
ORDER BY T2.ID,
        T2.VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the first value returned through `ROW_NUMBER()` function, so filter out by `rn = 1` within your statement. Moreover, you need to bring only one column `value` from the subquery, because there's only one column `t1.value` preceding `IN` operator as counterpart :

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET t1.count_val = NVL( t1.count_val, 0 ) + 1
 WHERE t1.value IN (
                    SELECT value
                      FROM
                      (
                        SELECT t2.*,
                               ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t2.id ORDER BY t2.value ) 
                            AS rn
                          FROM table2 t2
                         WHERE t2.value_ref = 'HGV00005x'
                      )
                     WHERE rn = 1 
                    )
```

Indeed, the error raises due to the `ORDER BY` within the subquery, it has already no aim for success even whether it was usable there, and `ORDER BY` has already been used within the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update (increment) T1.VAL_COUNT with the count of matching T2.VALUE?

```
update t1
set val_count = nvl(val_count,0) + ( select count(*)
                                     from t2
                                     where t1.value = t2.value
                                     and t2.value_ref = 'HGV00005x'
                                     group by t2.value
                                     )
```

Working demo on [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=12b5d3c4287c24c4c8c3db334c5ecbf9)